# What exactly is this API and what is it doing?

Tags: c#, api, external, dllimport

I know you are gonna hate me for that kind of question. But could somebody tell me what the following code is doing?

I mean there are some libraries loaded, i get that. plus there are some methods, still I don't get it.

F.e.:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
```

Here is the code:

```
private static class API 
    {

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(
            int idHook,
            HookDel lpfn,
            IntPtr hMod,
            uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(
            IntPtr hhk,
            int nCode,
            IntPtr wParam,
            IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(
            string lpModuleName);
    }
```

You do not have to explain it to me line for line. At least give me some reference where I can read it up, please.

Thx in advance!

Comment: All that code does is declare some methods that will be provided by P/Invoke. By itself it doesn't do anything. How are those methods used at runtime is more important to answer what they are being used for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is using [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx) to allow C# code to call several Win32 API functions related to [Windows Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589.aspx).

The posted code only defines the methods; it doesn't call them, so it doesn't do anything by itself. It just allows you to use the methods from other parts of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an older [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx) article explaining P/Invoke and what's going on.  Hopefully this helps you.

What the code is doing is allowing your managed C# code to call unmanaged Win32 API functions.

Here's also a [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) on MSDN that walks you through the P/Invoke process of creating code like your question has.

Answer (score 1):

`DllImport` is used to call unmanaged code/API in .Net/Managed code. All the code you've posted is trying to work with the `window` object of Win32 API.

References:

[DLLImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

[Win32 API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API)

[Win32 API to .Net API map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302340.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Your program somewhere is installing a hook into windows hook chain to monitor some events.

The dllimport attribute itself lets the program to invoke win32 api functions like the previous answer mentions.